# How to create a mock object when it doesn't have the default constructor?

Tags: junit, powermockito

I am working on Junit by using powermockito.

I have sample code like below:

```java
class A {
    private B b;

    A() {
        b = new B("Test");
    }

    public void invokeAnotherClassMethod() {
        String busineeslogic = b.myLogic();
        System.out.println("apply some logic again on this response ");
    }
}
```

```java
class B {
    private String text;

    B(String text) {
        this.text=text;
    }

    public String myLogic() {
        System.out.println("Need to apply some business logic");
        return "businessResponse";
    }
}
```

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
class ATest {

    @Before
    void setup() {
        B b = mock(B.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void mytestcase() {

    }
}
```

I am writing the Junit for the **Class A** and trying to mock the Class B object in my test case it is throwing the error, I am not getting how to create a mock object for the class B.

Can some one please guide me, how to create the mock object for the class B and use it in class A while executing the testcase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create mock inside you test or in the field of test class like:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
class ATest {

@Mock
private B b;

    @Test
    public void mytestcase() {
    when(b.myLogic()).thenReturn(anyString());
    }
}
```

or

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
class ATest {


    @Test
    public void mytestcase() {
    B b = mock(B.class);
    when(b.myLogic()).thenReturn(anyString());
    }
```

}